# LOAD DATA FROM S3 - Fastest way for big data and indexes

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, bigdata

I have a table that consists of holiday deals, so just to give you an idea, each row will contain the following bits of data:

```
Departure airport
Arrival airport
Start date
Duration
Hotel destination
Resort
Hotel name
Hotel rating
A few tiny integer columns for 1s and 0s.
Price
Date time the row was updated
```

Now, all of these deals get packaged up from 3 tables, they are `flights`, `accommodation` and `transfers`, the packaging up is to find the cheapest deal per variation such as, per departure airport, duration, board basis etc.

The table I am importing into will consist of around about 50 million rows, the import is extremely slow.

I have removed the indexes, that made a massive difference but now when I re-add the indexes back to the table after all data is in there it takes forever to complete.

I would like to know is there a way of bulk loading data quickly or is there a quicker way of adding indexes back to the table after data has been added?

Create Table

```

```
    CREATE TABLE `iv_deals` (
    `aid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Deal Autonumber PK',
    `startdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Holiday Start Date',
    `startdatet` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `depairport` CHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Departure Airport IATA Code',
    `arrairport` CHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Arrival Airport IATA Code',
    `destination` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Holiday Destination',
    `resort` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Holiday Resort',
    `hotel` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Holiday Property Name',
    `iv_PropertyID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Holiday Property ID',
    `rating` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Holiday Property Star Rating',
    `board` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Holiday Meal Option',
    `duration` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Holiday Duration',
    `2for1` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is 2nd Week FREE Offer, 0 = False, 1 = True',
    `3for2` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is 3rd Week FREE Offer, 0 = False, 1 = True',
    `3and4` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is 3rd and 4th Week FREE Offer, 0 = False, 1 = True',
    `4for3` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is 4th Week FREE Offer, 0 = False, 1 = True',
    `freebb` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Free Week Meal Option',
    `adults` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Number of Adults',
    `children` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Number of Children',
    `infants` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Number of Infants',
    `price` SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '9999' COMMENT 'Price',
    `carrier` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Flight Carrier IATA Code',
    `DateUpdated` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`aid`, `startdatet`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Unique` (`startdate`, `depairport`, `arrairport`, `iv_PropertyID`, `board`, `duration`, `adults`, `children`, `startdatet`),
    INDEX `ik_Price` (`price`),
    INDEX `ik_Destination` (`destination`),
    INDEX `ik_Resort` (`resort`),
    INDEX `ik_DepAirport` (`depairport`),
    INDEX `ik_Startdate` (`startdate`),
    INDEX `ik_Board` (`board`),
    INDEX `ik_FILTER_ALL` (`price`, `depairport`, `destination`, `resort`, `board`, `startdate`),
    INDEX `iv_PropertyID` (`iv_PropertyID`),
    INDEX `ik_Duration` (`duration`),
    INDEX `rating` (`rating`),
    INDEX `adults` (`adults`),
    INDEX `DirectFromPrice` (`iv_PropertyID`, `depairport`, `arrairport`, `board`, `duration`, `adults`, `children`, `startdate`),
    INDEX `DirectFromPrice_wo_depairport` (`iv_PropertyID`, `arrairport`, `board`, `duration`, `adults`, `children`),
    INDEX `DirectFromPrice_w_pid_dep` (`iv_PropertyID`, `depairport`, `adults`, `children`, `price`),
    INDEX `DirectFromPrice_w_pid_night` (`iv_PropertyID`, `duration`, `adults`, `children`),
    INDEX `DirectFromPrice_Dur_Board` (`iv_PropertyID`, `duration`, `board`, `adults`, `children`),
    INDEX `join_index` (`destination`, `startdate`, `duration`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
AUTO_INCREMENT=1258378560
/*!50100 PARTITION BY LIST (startdatet)
(PARTITION part0 VALUES IN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part1 VALUES IN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part2 VALUES IN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part3 VALUES IN (4) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part4 VALUES IN (5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part5 VALUES IN (6) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part6 VALUES IN (7) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part7 VALUES IN (8) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part8 VALUES IN (9) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part9 VALUES IN (10) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part10 VALUES IN (11) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part11 VALUES IN (12) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part12 VALUES IN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB)  */;
```

```

Comment: Need to see the datatypes.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, including the indexes.  Also need to see some of the important `SELECTs`; part of the issue is to pick the best indexes and toss the rest.

Comment: I hope, for example, that "airports" are `CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET ascii`.

Comment: @RickJames They are CHAR(3) but might not be "ascii", would that make a massive difference?

Comment: ascii - Not a massive diff.  latin1 would be essentially equivalent to ascii; utf8/utf8mb4 would be overkill and might waste space.  But I do need the `CREATE TABLE` to help with the performance question.

Comment: Hi @RickJames, please see the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 50M rows, but `AUTO_INCREMENT=1258378560`, let point out another problem that is looming.  (It may be related to the slow load.)

```
`aid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

allows only 4 billion; you are already at 1.2 billion.  Do a little math to estimate when you will run out of ids.  The brute force solution is to change to `BIGINT`, but let's analyze *why* the ids are being 'burned'.  There are several ways that `INSERT`/`REPLACE`/etc can throw away ids.  Please describe how the import is working.  `REPLACE` is perhaps the worst -- it burns ids *and* is effectively `DELETE` + `INSERT`.  Other techniques are faster.

(I will now ramble in many directions...)

The partitioning by month (which I assume you are doing with (`startdatet`) probably does not add any performance.  What has your experience been?  (I usually argue against using `PARTITION` except for the few use cases where there are benefits.  I see no benefit in your case.)

19 indexes means 19 BTrees that must be updated.  The 2 uniques ones must be checked before the `INSERT` is finished; the 17 others can be delayed, but not forever.  (The details are discussed under "change buffer".)

How much RAM?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  It should be about 70% of RAM.  The Change buffer is a portion of that.

I see at least 4 indexes that can be dropped, since other indexes handle their need.  In general, if you have `INDEX(a, b)`, you don't also need `INDEX(a)`.  (Shrinking from 19 indexes to 15 will help *some*.)

Flags and other things of low cardinality are virtually useless by them selves as indexes.  The Optimizer will decide that it is cheaper to scan the table than to bounce between the index's BTree and the data BTree.  I'm thinking of `INDEX(rating)`.

Any `SELECT` that does *not* have `startdatet` in the `WHERE` is likely to be *slower* than without partitioning.  This is because the query must check all 13 partitions.  Even with `AND startdatet = 4`, performance won't be any better than if there had been an index that included startdatet.

Let me discuss any index *starting* with a column (perhaps `price`, `rating`, `startdate`) that is queried as a "range" (eg, `WHERE price BETWEEN ...`).  The processing cannot use any columns after that column.  I suspect `ik_FILTER_ALL` will scan a big chunk of the index, since it only filtered on `price`.  Rearrange the columns.  Based on the name, I am guessing this is a "covering" index.  That is, a common query references only those 6 columns?  Note: `SELECT * ...` references more than just those 6, so the index is not "covering".  (Show us the query; I can discuss it more.)

The 5 "DirectFromPrice" indexes are probably each 'perfect' for some query.  But they are awfully long (lots of columns).  I would *guess* that 2 shorter lists would come close to handling the 5 cases "well enough".  (Remember, decreasing the number of indexes will help in the goal of insert time.)

What version of MySQL/MariaDB are you using?

The main action item at this point:  Show us the import.  (I will discuss sorting the input after seeing the method being used.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

In terms of `AUTO_INCREMENT=1258378560` this is because we use statements such as `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, we do this because we never want a day where this data is not there and also the deals are built over time, we do not get a full 50 million in one day but more over 3/4 days.

*Partitions*
That is interesting, I may leave this off to see if I we actually need it, I think it helped a lot in terms of performance but that was a while back now.

62GB of RAM, Aurora RDS MySQL compatible, the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is set to 52GB I think.